# Including additional data at each stage of a loop

Tags: r

I am trying to create minimum convex polygons for a set of GPS coordinates, each day has 32 coordinates and I want to create a MCP with 1 day,2 days,3 days... and so on worth of data. For instance in the first step I want to include rows 1-32 which I have managed:

```r
mydata <- read.csv("file.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
mydata <- mydata[1:32, ]
```

Currently to select data for me to do 2 days at a time I have written:

```r
mydata <- read.csv("file.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
mydata <- mydata[1:64, ]
```

Is there a way to automate adding 32 rows at each step (in a loop) rather than me running the code manually each time and changing the amount of data used manually each time?

I am very new to `R` so I do not know whether it is possible to do this, the way I thought would work was:

```r
n <- 32
for (i in 1:100) {
  mydata <- mydata[1:n, ]
  ## CREATE MCP AND STORE HOME RANGE OUTPUT
  n <- n+32
}
```

However it is not possible to have `n` representing a row number but is there a way to do this?

Apologies if this is unclear but as I said I am quite new to using `R` and really would appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible to have n represent a line number? What error message are you getting?

Comment: `n<-32;  mydata<-mydata[1:n,]` is perfectly fine to do.

Comment: Thank you very much I must have made a silly error before but I have it working now